# Illegal base64 character 7b

Tags: java

Im trying to decode a base64 string in order to generate an excel file

Im using the base64 decode method for the above stated purpose

```
public Response addToDB(String base64){

    try{
        s=sf.openSession();
        tx=s.beginTransaction();
        /*FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Ayesha.Syed/Desktop/eclipse_neon/students.xlsx")); 
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); */
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
        ByteArrayInputStream st = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(st); 
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        /*int starRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();*/
        /*int endRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();*/

        XSSFRow row;

        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

            //points to the starting of excel i.e excel first row

            Student stud=new Student();
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            stud.setRollnumber(row.getCell(0).toString());
            System.out.println(row.getCell(0).getCellTypeEnum());

            stud.setName(row.getCell(1).toString());
            System.out.println(row.getCell(1).getCellTypeEnum());

            stud.setEnglish(row.getCell(2).toString());
            System.out.println(row.getCell(2).getCellTypeEnum());

            stud.setHindi(row.getCell(3).toString());
            System.out.println(row.getCell(3).getCellTypeEnum());

            stud.setMaths(row.getCell(4).toString());
            System.out.println(row.getCell(4).getCellTypeEnum());

            stud.setMarks(  row.getCell(5).toString());
            System.out.println(row.getCell(5).getCellTypeEnum());

            stud.setPercentage(row.getCell(6).toString());
            System.out.println(row.getCell(6).getCellTypeEnum());

            s.save(stud);
        }
        response.setStatus("200");
        response.setMessage("succesfull");
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());

        response.setStatus("500");
        response.setMessage("unsuccesfull");
        tx.rollback();

    } finally {
        s.close();
    }
    return response;
}
```

It is suppose to decode the string and generate an excel sheet along with the data i push through postman

Comment: The exception suggests that you're trying to decode a value containing '{' which isn't valid in base64. Are you *certain* this is actually base64? Could you edit your post with some sample data? (If you could also format your code, that would be very useful - use the preview to make sure it looks like the kind of post you'd want to read.)

Comment: Indeed looks like JSON, maybe something like `{ result: "base64..." }`.

Comment: To provide an answer, this needs to include the input data as well as exception, neither of which are present (though comments suggest maybe there were at some point in the past?).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Turns out i was getting the String directly from the request parameter and it included the entire JSON. Needs to parse the parameters to get the actual base64 encoded String.